# Haskell Stack ghci flags

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

Basically, I am trying to achieve the following:

`stack ghci --flag proj:dev`

but it seems that flag is not valid for ghci, only for `build`.

**How can I achieve this?**  If possible

*Notes:
`proj` is a cloned yesod-postgres template, I do not want to use yesod devel since I find it painfully slow. And I already have ghci to watch changes and notify browser-sync.

Comment: I think the `--flag` option for `stack ghci` had been accidentally removed. It's back in v1.4.0 so you probably just need to upgrade. If that doesn't work, please provide the error message you see.

Comment: Yes, it works, I had 1.3.x